# Popout menu is too touch sensitive

Tags: css, menu

I've developed a menu (it can be seen on the top of the page, Home About us Programs are the buttons.), when a user hovers over this menu, a sub menu pops out, and the mouse can then select different options. This works well, but the popout sub menu doesn't stay open when trying to navigate from the parent navigation to the options. You need to get really precise.

https://tcokchallenge.com/launch3

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the disadvantage of using CSS only to create a dropdown menu,

Add this line for some improvments, Good luck.

```
.menu li {
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```